# If SO$(3,\mathbb C)$ is isomorphic to PGL$(2,\mathbb C)$, what objects do vectors in $\mathbb C^3$ represent in the context of Möbius geometry?

Tags: complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables, lie-groups, conformal-geometry

I hope this question isn't too basic or ambiguous for this site.

The following is an explicit isomorphism from $\mathrm{PGL}(2,\mathbb C)$ to $\mathrm{SO}(3,\mathbb C)$:

$$\left[\begin{matrix}p & q\\r & s\end{matrix}\right] \mapsto \left[\begin{matrix}p s + q r & i p r + i q s & - p r + q s\\- i p q - i r s & \frac{p^{2}}{2} + \frac{q^{2}}{2} + \frac{r^{2}}{2} + \frac{s^{2}}{2} & \frac{i p^{2}}{2} - \frac{i q^{2}}{2} + \frac{i r^{2}}{2} - \frac{i s^{2}}{2}\\- p q + r s & - \frac{i p^{2}}{2} - \frac{i q^{2}}{2} + \frac{i r^{2}}{2} + \frac{i s^{2}}{2} & \frac{p^{2}}{2} - \frac{q^{2}}{2} - \frac{r^{2}}{2} + \frac{s^{2}}{2}\end{matrix}\right]$$
where $i^2 = -1$.

Given that this isomorphism exists, I'm wondering whether points in $\mathbb C^3$ stand for geometrically meaningful objects in the Möbius plane or Riemann sphere.

Comment: It seems unlikely to me given that the dimension (over $\mathbb R$) of the unit sphere in $\mathbb C^3$ is 4, while it takes only 3 parameters to describe a generalised circle in the plane. But I still thought it was worth asking

Comment: By the unit sphere, I mean the set of solutions to $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$ where $x, y, z$ are complex numbers

Comment: This is the adjoint representation, so vectors in $\mathbb{C}^3$ can be interpreted as infinitesimal Mobius transformations.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Ah, thanks. That gives me something to read about

Comment: You can identify the Lie algebra $sl_2(C)$ with the algebra of quadratic vector fields on $CP^1$. These will be the infinitesimal Moebius transformations mentioned by Qiaochu.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Can you explain what a quadratic vector field is? And can you describe the precise relationship between it and $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb C)$? Thanks.

Comment: @MoisheKohan My guess is that you take the linear approximation of $\frac{z \left(\epsilon p + 1\right) + \epsilon q}{z(\epsilon r) + (\epsilon s + 1)}$ where $\epsilon \approx 0$ to get $\epsilon q - \epsilon r z^{2} - z \left(- \epsilon p + \epsilon s - 1\right)$ which is indeed quadratic in $z$

Comment: @ogogmad: In terms of the Riemann sphere ${\mathbb C}\cup \infty$, quadratic vector fields, as the name suggests, are $(az^2+bz+c)\frac{\partial }{\partial z}$. Linear-fractional transformations preserve the space of such vector fields (which is 3-dimensional) and the action is isomorphic to the adjoint representation.

Comment: ... unsurprisingly, since $SL(2,C)$ has unique (up to isomorphism) irreducible linear representation of the given finite dimension $n\ge 2$ (in this case, $n=3$).